# I fixed intellij Idea not giving autocomplete suggestions on imported classes, but now it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'"

Tags: intellij-idea

My goal is for IntelliJ Idea IDE to run normally, meaning:

1. Offer autocomplete suggestions from imported files/classes.
2. Import from packages without complaint.

My expected result is that Idea IDE will offer autocomplete suggestions, build and rebuild the project on demand, and overall enable instead of disable my ability to code.

My problem started when Idea IDE would not give autocomplete suggestions. Example:

```
public void createTableIfNotExists() {
        this.adSqlMaker.cre // there should be a dropdown that shows "createAdsTableIfNotExists" but it doesn't show that.
        String createTableStatement = this.adSqlMaker.createAdsTableIfNotExists();
        this.executionEngine.executeWithoutReturn(createTableStatement);
         this.f // this completes to "foo" in a dropdown
    }

public void foo() {
        // in the same file
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
```

It's a painful hindrance while coding.

To make autocomplete work, I had to right click the `/src` folder and choose "Mark directory as" and then "Sources Root." This made autocomplete work. Simultaneously, it caused the following error:

```
package com.pluto.storage.controllers;
// says "Package name 'com.pluto.storage.service' does not correspond to the file path 'main.java.com.pluto.storage.service'" with a big red underline

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
// "springframework" is in red text with the dropdown that says "Cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'"
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. I tried File => Invalidate Cache and Restart. This fails.
2. I tried "Build => Build Project" and the alternative, "Rebuild Project." This fails with the error "java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist"
3. I tried deleting the `.idea` folder. Now "Rebuild Project" works, but now my autocomplete suggestions don't work again. So I have to redo marking `/src` as "Sources Root" but that puts me back to the beginning.
4. I tried running `./gradlew clean build`. No effect.

What do I do?

I've seen numerous threads about similar issues. There's lots of talk about using solutions I showed above, such as "mark /src as sources root" and "invalidate cache and restart," but none talk about escaping this circular problem.

edit: I suspect it's relevant that my folder structure is a monorepo containing three parts of my project.

```
/project-name
... /.idea
.../collector
.../storage
.../untitled
.../out // this is my java's production code
```

My java project lives in `/storage` and I suspect this affects the IDE

Comment: The error resembles https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255367, but it's hard to guess without seeing the whole structure of a project and build files